# Python comparing two matrices produces error

Tags: python, numpy

Hello I have the following code which transposes one matrix and compares it to the original matrix in order to check if the matrix is symetrical.

```
def sym(x):
    
    mat = x
    transpose = 0;
    
    (m,n) = x.shape
    if(m != n):
        print("Matrix must be square")
        return
    else:
        transpose = ([[x[j][i] for j in range(len(x))] for i in range(len(x[0]))])
        print(transpose)
        print(x)
        if(transpose == mat):
           print("Symetrical")
        else:
           print("Not symetrical")
            
        return
    
    A = np.random.rand(5,5)
    SymMatrix = (A + A.T)/2
    sym(SymMatrix)
```

I recieve the following data from the prints:

```
[[0.17439677739055337, 0.4578837676040824, 0.35842887026076997, 0.8610456087667133,      0.2967753611380975], [0.4578837676040824, 0.6694101430064164, 0.6718596412137644, 0.5107862111816033, 0.6429698779871544], [0.35842887026076997, 0.6718596412137644, 0.5387701626024015, 0.708555677626843, 0.5756758392540096], [0.8610456087667133, 0.5107862111816033, 0.708555677626843, 0.37095928395815847, 0.7062962356554356], [0.2967753611380975, 0.6429698779871544, 0.5756758392540096, 0.7062962356554356, 0.3807024190850993]]

    [[0.17439678 0.45788377 0.35842887 0.86104561 0.29677536]
     [0.45788377 0.66941014 0.67185964 0.51078621 0.64296988]
     [0.35842887 0.67185964 0.53877016 0.70855568 0.57567584]
     [0.86104561 0.51078621 0.70855568 0.37095928 0.70629624]
     [0.29677536 0.64296988 0.57567584 0.70629624 0.38070242]]
```

along with this error:

```
  The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The first issue i see is that the transposes matrix has extra decimals in each value which i dont understand and I am not sure if this is the cause of the error. Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should have also done a `print` of `transpose == mat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is trying to compare two ndarrays, which results in something like this:

```
transpose == mat
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

The 'if' statement does not know which boolean he should pick. Should it be `True`if **any** of the values are `True`, or only if **all** values are `True`?

To indicate that **all** values should be `True`, add: `.all()` to your statement:

`if((transpose == mat).all())`

This results in a single boolean (in this case: `True`).

Comment: Especially when using floats, I'd use `np.allclose`.

Comment: Interesting, did not know that one, very useful indeed!